# Eloquent relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm having following table structure:

```
Table Name - Users
    Column: id, name, email, etc

Table Name - Plugins
    Column: id, theme_id, type_id, code,

Table Name - Templates
    Column: id, theme_id, user_id, templatedata

Table Name - Userplugins
    Column: id, user_id, plugins_id, contents
```

Now I'm calling the route with id of the `templates`, in which `templatedata` has `JSON` data, i'm able to get `Plugins` `code` by following code in my blade file as:

```
@foreach($gettemplate as $renderer)

    {!! $plugins->find($renderer)->code !!}

@endforeach
```

but I'm unable to fetch contents in the `UserPlugins` table. Following is my `controller` where I'm trying to do so:

```
public function get_template($id)
{
    $template = Template::findOrFail($id);
    $gettemplate = json_decode($template->templatedata);
    $plugins = Plugins::all();
    $user = User::findorFail($id);
    return $user->userplugins()->contents;
    //return view('nitseditor.test', ['plugins' => $plugins, 'gettemplate' => $gettemplate, 'user' => $user]);
}
```

I've commented out my view just to check the output.
I've defined the `relationship` in the `model` my `App/User.php` file contains:

```
public function userplugins(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\UserPlugin');
}
```

And in `App\UserPlugin.php` file I've:

```
protected $fillable = [

    'contents',

];
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$contents

Please help me out, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line:

```
return $user->userplugins()->contents;
```

When you call `$user->userplugins()` that mean you call an relation method. It's will not return Eloquent Collection or Eloquent Object for you.

You need to call

```
$user->userplugins
```

to get collection of UserPlugin

However, when you call

```
return $user->userplugins->contents;
```

you will get error, becauese  `return $user->userplugins` is an Eloquent Collection, you can not get contents from it.

You can get the contents of specific UserPlugin. For example, the first UserPlugin of user like:

```
return $user->userplugins()->first()->contents;
```